# WFFM File Upload doesn't save the file to selected Media Library folder

Tags: wffm

I'm trying to find out the source of the following problem:
In my `WFFM` form I am using a single `File Upload field` to save the file to the selected folder in the `media library` after the form is submitted. It's a normal file upload from `WFFM` (no customizations).
However, after the form is submitted the file is not visible in the media library folder (any DB).

I'm also not seeing any errors in the logs during the form submission. Does anyone know what may be causing such an issue? Any tips and directions will be welcome as I'm quite confused about where to start searching since it's an OOTB functionality of `WFFM`.

Comment: Maybe this on can help? https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/3578/sitecore-wffm-file-upload-not-working-in-cd-enviornment

Comment: I guess you're checking master DB instead of Web, you can check configuration mentioned here: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/7004/wffm-how-to-move-uploaded-files-from-web-to-master-database